# Explanation or example of how to use ContentObserver in Delphi Application

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I am currently working on an Android Application developed in Delphi 10.2 and have most of the functionality that I need working. However I am trying to get my head around the following `SharedActivity.getContentResolver.registerContentObserver`. I what to use this for detecting when an SMS has been sent via `content://sms/sent` URI.

I have the code that will go and get the message using `sharedactivity.getcontentresolver.query` but just struggling with the `ContentObserver` part in Delphi. Have spent 2 days searching for an example but found nothing. Maybe it is not possible!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post some code as to what you have tried so far so others can better assist you.

Comment: It's not possible to do it without writing some Java code, namely to create a descendant of ContentObserver and a companion interface to use as a "listener". There's an example in the source supplied with Delphi, in the Java source in the rtl\androiddex\java\fmx\src\com\embarcadero\firemonkey\addressbook folder, and  they are consumed in the Delphi code in fmx\FMX.AddressBook.Android.pas. If I had time, I'd put together a more complete answer

Comment: Dave many thanks for this pointer I have taken a look and can start to see how it is being achieved in their example. What I don't entirely understand, which is due to my lack of knowledge, is the Java bit. Looking at their files I cannot see how the Java bit is referenced by Delphi. Please note my knowledge of Java is very limited. You mentioned that the Java is consumed by delphi but I don't see or understand this part. I took a look at http://www.pacifier.com/~mmead/borland/borcon2001/index.html#CallingJava but not sure if that is that starting point.

Comment: Perhaps there is a better way of detecting when an SMS has been sent from Delphi? But I also want to get my head around ContentObserver challenge now. Many Thanks again.